# Passing Product ID and Vendor ID

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, port, libusb

I am trying to get details of a Dongle (GSM Modem) using `LibUSBDotNet` library ([here it is](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html)).

Following is my attempt

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using LibUsbDotNet;
using LibUsbDotNet.Descriptors;
using LibUsbDotNet.DeviceNotify;
using LibUsbDotNet.Info;
using LibUsbDotNet.LibUsb;
using LibUsbDotNet.LudnMonoLibUsb;
using LibUsbDotNet.Main;
using LibUsbDotNet.WinUsb;

namespace LibUsbDotNet_Test1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //RetrieveUSBDevices(12d1, 140c);
        }

        public static void RetrieveUSBDevices(int vid, int pid)
        {
            var usbFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(vid, pid);
            var usbDevices = new UsbRegDeviceList();
            var en = usbDevices.GetEnumerator();

            while (en.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(en.ToString());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems like I need to pass the Product ID (PID) and Vensor ID (VID) as integers. But my PID and VID contains letters! Please have a look at the below image, which is showing details about my device.

[image]

How can I pass my PID and VID in this case? Or I am doing something wrong? I need to print the device description and get the "port name" of the dongle and that's why I am doing all these to identify it.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem the VendorID and ProductID are hexadecimal numbers, but the library you are using wants integer numbers.

```
string productID = "140c";
int pid = Convert.ToInt32(productID, 16);
// or if you don't like "base 16" and want to have self-documenting code:
pid = Int32.Parse(productID, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```